# WPF DataGrid combobox change selection issue

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with one column that has a ComboBox in it:

```
    DataGridTemplateColumn colDataType = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    colDataType.Header = "Type";
    var cboFactoryDT = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
    cboFactoryDT.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, Enum.GetValues(typeof(BuilderDataTypes)).Cast<BuilderDataTypes>());
    b = new Binding("Value[1]");
    b.Converter = new ObjectToDataTypeConverter();
    b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
    b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    cboFactoryDT.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedIndexProperty, b);
    cboFactoryDT.SetValue(ComboBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemProperty, true);
    DataTemplate dtDT = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = cboFactoryDT };
    colDataType.CellTemplate = dtDT;
```

And my Converter class is:

```
public class ObjectToDataTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return int.Parse(value.ToString());
        }
        catch { return 0; }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return value;
        }
        catch { return 0; }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is when I change the selection in one of the rows, all the comboboxes in all the rows are changed to the same selection as well.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing exception handling like yours is a pet-pevee of mine. Your code has the abiltiy to swallow Fatal Exceptions, wich is a deadly sin of Exception handling. You should read these articles on proper exception handling:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

What wonders me even more, is that you do that faulty handling to Parse. If you do not want the Vexing Exceptions, there is TryParse just for that. The only reason to not use it, is if you somehow are below Framework Version 2.0, where it was introduced. I have repalcement code for that case, but with WPF that seems unlikely.

Comment: I know that the variable bound to my combobox column may be null, so in that case it will raise an exception which will return 0 to make the combobox select the first item

Comment: In that case, any parse exception and any **other** exception, the exception will be swallowed and return 0. TryParse explicitly deals with the null case. And there is short syntax to check for null cases since C# 6.0 or so. Your poor reasons only make the mistake worse.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I'll fix it. Thanks for the advice. But do you have a solution to the main issue?

Comment: It is hard to say. If you swallow excptions, you get all kinds of non-understandable followup Behavior. And you might have similar faults in other code. Honestly it is really confusing that you generate the Columns in Code behind to begin with. That is what Row and Type Targetting Data Templates are there for. WPF/UWP was designed for with MVVM Pattern in mind and that does not look like MVVM pattern at all. I wrote a short intro a few years ago, maybe it can help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf